# How to use COUNTIFS with two specific instances on two different sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-365

I am getting an error message.

=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!B2:B33, "Serial Examples", Sheet2!B2:B35, "Logos")

I am wanting to get a total of the number of occurences when these two criteria are met.

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Please offer a suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ranges Sheet1!B2:B33 and Sheet2!B2:B35 are not the same size